# Modifying CSS keyframes from angular 2 component

Tags: css, angular

I have an animation that fills a table cell with a color.  I want the animations keyframes `to.width` to be a variable that is controlled by an angular 2 component.

CSS:

```
#passing {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #81C784;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: slideright;
}

@keyframes slideright {
  from {
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    margin-right: 50%;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="passing"
     [style.width.%]="cells[id].width"
     [style.keyframes.slideright.to.width.%]="cells[id].width">
</div>
```

The `[style.width.%]` works fine but I want to do something like the above to set the animation width dynamically for each cell but I am not sure how to access that attribute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to solve this by removing the `to` declaration in the CSS and setting the value with `[ngStyle]` in the view.

New CSS:

```
#passing {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #81C784;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: slideright;
}

@keyframes slideright {
  from {
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

New HTML:

```
<div id="passing"
     [style.width.%]="cells[id].width"
     [ngStyle]="{'to': cells[id].width}">
</div>
```

Comment: how can angular understand what *keyframe* is the rule referring to? An element can have different keyframes. Sounds like a hack to me

Comment: CSS variables together with Angular 9+ allow cleaner solution. @CristianTraìna have a look at my answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63506012/5135171](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63506012/5135171)

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution based on CSS variables, that get updated by Angular dynamically via `@HostBinding`.

The CSS declaration stays almost the same, but uses a CSS variable to determine the target width of the keyframe (with an optional default value of `50%`).

```
#passing {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #81C784;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: slideright;
}

@keyframes slideright {
  from {
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    margin-right: 50%;
    width: var(--target-width, 50%);
  }
}
```

To update the value of `--target-width`, add a variable to your Angular component and annotate it with [`@HostBinding()`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding):

```
@HostBinding('style.--target-width')
private targetWidth: string = '60%';
```

This will add the CSS variable to the component host element. Since CSS variables cascade down you can use it anywhere within the host component's template styling.

You can now use the member to update the CSS variable at runtime and assign it any value.

Sidenotes:

- Be aware that bindings to `camelCase` properties will be converted to `camel-case`.
- According to this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9343) this approach only works for Angular 9+.

Comment: whill the animation be updated everytime the variable gets updated?

Comment: A wonderful solution <3